# What's the best way to calling a Stored Procedure using Hibernate in a Generic DAO?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, genericdao

I'm using MySql and my query to call is like:

```
call SPGetChart (idNumber, nameChart);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using EntityManager

```
   Query query=getEntityManager().
                           createNativeQuery("BEGIN SPGetChart(:id, :name); END;");
   query.setParameter("id", idValue);
   query.setParameter("name", nameChart);

   query.executeUpdate();
```

Using connection through EntityManager:

```
   Connection con = ((SessionImpl) getEntityManager().getDelegate()).connection();
   CallableStatement callableStatement = cc.prepareCall("{call SPGetChart (?,?)}");

   callableStatement.setInt(1, idValue);
   callableStatement.setString(2, nameChart);
   callableStatement.execute();
```

Using Session:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL SPGetChart (:id, :name)")
               .setParameter("id", idValue)
                   .setParameter("name", nameChart);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I'm using an another approach, look this: http://jsfiddle.net/2TZA2/

I dont have a session or  a getSession. In the DataSource I cannot found a "createSQLQuery"

How should to be changed this file?

Comment: @HelioBentzen: I see that you have `getEntityManager`. I updated the answer to use the same.

Comment: I need make some tests to say it, but dont was error. Thanks. I'll say here when I finish.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a old question but for those that find this now, the EntityManager class now has support for stored procedures now.

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = getEntityManager().createStoredProcedureQuery("SPGetChart");

query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);

query.setParameter(1, idValue);
query.setParameter(2, nameChart);
query.execute();
```